# JoinColumn on ManyToOne column

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-2.6

i want to join an entity to another one by the second entity's logical primary key.

Say, i have these entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Configuration
{

    /**
     * @var Dataset
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dataset", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns(
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="line", referencedColumnName="line"),
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="detailtype", referencedColumnName="detailtype"),
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="type_id"),
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="mandator_id", referencedColumnName="mandator_id")
     * )
     */
    private $dataset;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="line", type="string", length=2)
     */
    private $line;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="detailtype", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $detailtype;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $typeId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mandator_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $mandatorId;

}

/**
 * Dataset
 *
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     uniqueConstraints = {
 *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(
 *             name="uq_dataset",
 *             columns={"type_id", "mandator_id", "line", "detailtype"}
 *         )
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Dataset
{

    /**
     * @var Type
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Type")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var Mandator
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Mandator")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="mandator_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $mandator;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="line", type="string", length=2)
     */
    private $line;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="detailtype", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $detailtype;

}
```

When i execute `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`, I get the error

```
[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]

Column name `type_id` referenced for relation from Configuration towards Dataset does not exist.
```

Does this have to do with the `JoinColumn`s being `ManyToOne` in `Dataset`. If so, how can i build such a relationship regardless of these circumstances? I cannot use the generated `id` value for joining as the `Datasets` will be deleted and recreated very often so that the ID will change every time. The logical primary key will stay none the less.

---

**EDIT 1**

The database looks like this:

- Mandator

  - PK id
- Type

  - PK id
- Dataset

  - PK id
  - Unique Key

    - mandator_id, FK on Mandator
    - type_id, FK on Type
    - line
    - detailtype
- Configuration

  - PK id
  - shall have an FK on the Unique Key of Dataset as this is the logical Primary Key

Comment: I cannot see any `mappedBy=""` annotation along with your `targetEntity=""` in your `Dataset` entity. Is that normal?

Comment: as far as the documentation goes, a `mappedBy` attribute is only necessary on `*ToMany` annotations

Comment: How can you have `ManyToOne` relationships on both your entities? Shouldn't be `ManyToOne` on the first entity, then `OneToMany` on the other? Or I'm not properly getting what you are meaning.. :)

Comment: i added a brief summary of the database, i hope this helps understanding the problem